# iOS Facebook sdk: How to get user feeds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I need to get the facebook user feeds, i tried the following code:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"read_stream"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state,NSError *error)
 {
     [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                           completionHandler:^(
                                               FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                               id result,
                                               NSError *error
                                               ) {
                               if (error)
                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                               else
                                   NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                           }];


 }];
```

I got the error:

**Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)**

Please do help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link solves the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669850/ios-facebook-sdk-how-to-get-user-feeds#autocomment36363544